# Cant render my component data correctly in 'React Native' - 'Using Axios'

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently, I'm having a weird issue with regards to rendering my API. (I'm using Expo GO)

I'm using `Axios`, which calls the API inside of a `UseEffect` once I get location of the device.
The problem I'm facing is that the screen only renders the fetched data once I save or `cntrl+s` on VS Code.

I've tried to log the array, get nothing once the function is called.
I've also tried adding a button to call the function instead, only then it renders, which makes sense as it triggers a `re-render`.

WHEN I ENTER THE COMPONENT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3npmm.png)

WHEN I SAVE THE FILE, IT THEN FETCHES DATA:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfSQV.png)

Would be much appreciated if anyone can help, maybe I'm missing some basic knowledge of how this works. Thanks guys!

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, ScrollView, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import { winners } from '../screens/MainScreen';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';


const API = () => {

  

  const resturant = winners;
  
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const [NamesFound, setNamesFound] = useState(0);

  const APIKey ='xxxxxxxxxx';
  const [Result, SetResult] = useState([]);
  const [Names, SetNames] = useState([]);
  
  const [lat, Setlat] = useState();
  const [long, Setlong] = useState();
  
  // const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
  const [RestAddress, setRestAddress] = useState([]);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  const wait = (timeout) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
  }

    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
      setRefreshing(true);
      wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
    }, []);
  
  const SampleFunction=(item)=>{
 
    Alert.alert(item);
 
  }

  
  const getLocation = () => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      }

      Location.setGoogleApiKey(APIKey);

      // console.log(status)

      let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

      // setLocation(coords);

      Setlat(coords.latitude);
      Setlong(coords.longitude);

      if (coords) {
        let { longitude, latitude } = coords;

        let regionName = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
          longitude,
          latitude,
        });
        setAddress(regionName[0].city);
        console.log(regionName[0].city);
      }

    })();
  };


 
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location='+lat+','+long+'&key='+APIKey+'&status=&query='+resturant,
    headers: { }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          SetResult(response.results);
          console.log(Result.map((name)=> name.name));
          SetNames(Result.map((name)=> name.name))
          setNamesFound(Names.length);
          console.log('API function called.')
          console.log (Names);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
    
      getLocation();
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);
  
     
  return(
    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      
      {loading && <Text>Loading....</Text>}
      {!loading && isFocused && (
        <><Text style={styles.MainText}>{NamesFound} {winners}s within {address}</Text><ScrollView
          style={styles.scroll}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl
            refreshing={refreshing}
            onRefresh={onRefresh} />}
        >
          {Names.map((item, key) => (
            <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={SampleFunction.bind(this, item)}> {item} </Text>)
          )}
        </ScrollView></>
      )}
    
      {/* <Button title='CLICK ME FOR API' onPress={CallAPI} style={styles.btn}></Button> */}
      
      
      
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change these lines

```
  useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          SetResult(response.results);
          console.log(Result.map((name)=> name.name));
          SetNames(Result.map((name)=> name.name))
          setNamesFound(Names.length);
          console.log('API function called.')
          console.log (Names);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
    
      getLocation();
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);
```

to something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          const newResult = response.results;
          SetResult(newResult);

          const newNames = newResult.map((name)=> name.name);
          console.log(newNames);
          SetNames(newNames)
          setNamesFound(newNames.length);
          console.log('API function called.')
          console.log (newNames);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
    
      getLocation();
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);
```

Please notice how I use `newResult` and `newName`, which are derived from the immediate `response`, to set the states instead of using the state variable `Result` and `Names`.

To understand the reason,

1. You have to know that setting a state variable by using its setter (e.g. `SetResult`, `SetNames` will not immediately assign the value to the variable.

```
// This is the 1st time React calls your function
const [Result, SetResult] = useState([]); // Now Result = []
const [Names, SetNames] = useState([]); // Also Names = []

useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          SetResult(response.results);
          // Result still = [] here

          SetNames(Result.map((name)=> name.name))
          // Names still = [], likewise
  
          console.log('API function called.')
          console.log (Names);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
    
      getLocation();
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);
```

2. React "re-render" when the state variable's setter is called, and the value is then assigned to the variable.

```
// This is the 2nd time React calls your function
// , and it does so because you call SetResult
const [Result, SetResult] = useState([]); // Now Result = [...] <-- now it has value 
const [Names, SetNames] = useState([]); // Also Names = [] <-- but this is still an empty list
```

```
// This is the 3rd time React calls your function
// , and it does so because you call SetNames
const [Result, SetResult] = useState([]); // Now Result = [...] <-- now it has value 
const [Names, SetNames] = useState([]); // Also Names = [...] <-- now it has value
```

If you really want to make a state variable to depend on another variable, you can do it like this (though not need for the case in your question).

```
const [Result, SetResult] = useState([]);
const [Names, SetNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          SetResult(response.results);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
   
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    SetNames(Result.map((name)=> name.name))
  }, [Result]);
```

In your case, I think it's better to do like this

```
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
const names = result.map((name)=> name.name);
const namesFound = names.length;

useEffect(() => {
  
      const fetchData = async () =>{
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const {data: response} = await axios(config);
          setResult(response.results);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
   
      fetchData();
    
  }, []);
```

Tip: I rename the variables to make the leading characters lower case, this is the convention, and it will make your code more readable to other developers.